# How to fix the Principle Component Analysis error in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I happened to  a Matlab Problem, the error looks like this:

```
Error using pca
Too many input arguments.

Error in mdscale (line 413)
[~,score] = pca(Y,'Economy',false);

Error in demo_libsvm_test1 (line 140)
newCoor = mdscale(distanceMatrix,2);
```

When I debug my code step by step, the error comes from here:

```
distanceMatrix = pdist(heart_scale_inst,'euclidean'); (line 139)
newCoor = mdscale(distanceMatrix,2);  (line 140)
```

Everything above the two lines are all right. I do not know how to fix the problem. I use Matlab 2014a. Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: It is likely that you have a function called `pca` in your path that overloads the actual `pca` function from Matlab. What is the output of `which('pca')`?

Comment: @Crazy Rat   the output is: toolbox\mvpa\netlab\pca.m

Comment: @CrazyRat, How to fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `mdscale` uses `pca`, but the mvpa toolbox redefines `pca` with different arguments. You could try removing the toolbox from your Matlab path (use `rmpath`).